# Get all the Order Ids based on the all the matching products in the Order details table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table

Order and Order details

Order details have product ids

I have requirement where if i pass product ids example 9,4,3,2,10,11,34

I need all the order id based on the exact match of the product in the order details table.

Please help me with a query to slow the above.

Comment: Show us your query to get help

Comment: or schema, or sql fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Probably try something like this using `group by` clause

```
SELECT o.* FROM Orders o 
JOIN Order_Details od on o.id = od.id 
GROUP BY o.id
HAVING od.product_id IN (9,4,3,2,10,11,34)
AND COUNT(od.product_id) >= 7
```